# UIButton appears in the wrong layer - Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uibutton, apple-push-notifications

I am using appoxee message service in my game..

My very first layer is "StartUpLayer" StartUpLayer waits for StageLayer to finish loading.. and goes to stage layer where my UIButton is declared..

However my UIButton appears in the StartUpLater for the first time and stays there until it's released.. How can I fix this problem? Thanks..

AppDelegate

```
- (void) AppoxeeNeedsToUpdateBadge:(int)badgeNum hasNumberChanged:(BOOL)hasNumberChanged
{

    if(badgeNum > 0)
    {
        badgeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",badgeNum];
    }

    StageLayer *stgLayer = [[StageLayer alloc] init];


    [[AppoxeeManager sharedManager] addBadgeToView:stgLayer.AppoxeeButton  badgeText:badgeText badgeLocation:CGPointMake(0,0) shouldFlashBadge:hasNumberChanged]; 

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNum;
}
```

Stage Layer init

```
AppoxeeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
            [AppoxeeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"messages-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [AppoxeeButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [AppoxeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(inboxPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:AppoxeeButton];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AproxeeButton` apeears not in the startUpLayer, but it appers on CCDirector openGL view. That is why it would be allways on the top of all cocos2d nodes and layers.

The answer on the question why it is shown when startUpLayer that

`StageLayer *stgLayer = [[StageLayer alloc] init];` is called in AppDelegate, so `AproxeeButton`   is shown after application starts.

Comment: true that.. I moved `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:AppoxeeButton];` to `-onEnterTransitionDidFinish` method from init and problem solved..